# Order of inherited dependencies in Maven 3

Tags: maven, inheritance, dependency-management

I am using Maven 3.0.4. Say I have a parent pom with dependency `dep-A` and a child pom, inheriting from the parent, with dependencies `dep-B` and `dep-C`. When I look at the effective pom of the child project, I see that the dependencies end up declared in the following order:

```
dep-B
dep-C 
dep-A
```

In other words, the inherited (parent) dependency was added at the **bottom** of the list. The problem is that I am using a custom Maven plugin for which dependency declaration order matters.

Is there a way to force Maven to add the list of inherited dependencies **above** the list of the child's?

Comment: Can you explain why the ordering matters?  What is broken because the dependencies are in the wrong order?

Comment: If you custom plugin: ` custom Maven plugin for which dependency declaration order matters` really relies on the order there something wrong with that plugin. The order is implicitly given by the dependencies between the modules. The modules will be sorted in topological order which gives the correct order.

Comment: This plugin was designed to build software components for a particular technology which isn't Java. This technology uses external libraries, a bit like jars, for which the import order matters. The dependency declaration order is used to determine the import order of the libraries, which has been very handy until we started using inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer: It is not possible to influence the order of (inherited/ self defined) dependencies in the list of dependencies in the final pom.

You could however maybe create a build scenario where you  generate the resulting/ final pom using http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html, override it with only the order of dependencies reordered according to your needs (easy if its always the same artefacts - a bit more of work if you need to dynamicially determine from which "level" you inherited certain dependencies) and use this pom.xml to run your custom plugin. (Thats just a bit of Brainstorming - i guess it would require at least two independant builds). So if you have any influence on the custom plugin you may be better off by changing the behaviour of that plugin.

**NOTE:** I am not aware off the effects to the build (reactor build order especially)  hence i recomend you make some simple manual tests (change the order and check if the build still works regardless of the custom-plugin) regarding this.

Comment: Thanks, your quick answer is what I wanted to know. Your suggestion is also very interesting, although in my case the "high-level" artifacts are not always the same so it might be a little tricky to identify them.